# How is $current_page passed in woocommerce_account_orders function?

Tags: functions, wp-query

The woocommerce function `woocommerce_account_orders($current_page)` has 1 parameter called `$current_page`. The function is called via `woocommerce_account_orders_endpoint` via the following hook - `add_action( 'woocommerce_account_orders_endpoint', 'woocommerce_account_orders' );`

However, in the above hook, `$current_page` is not passed as an argument in the function. How is `$current_page` passed to `woocommerce_account_orders()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Action hooks can pass variables do hooked callback functions. For example:

```
do_action( 'my_custom_action', $a_variable );
```

For that action, any callback function has access to `$a_variable`:

```
add_action( 'my_custom_action', 'my_custom_function' );

function my_custom_function( $a_variable ) {
     // etc.
}
```

The `woocommerce_account_orders_endpoint` action hook is defined like this:

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_account_' . $key . '_endpoint', $value );
```

Where `$value` would be passed to `woocommerce_account_orders()` which uses it as the `$current_page` argument.